# Constructor parameter validation in C# - Best practices

Tags: c#, validation, constructors

What is the best practice for constructor parameter validation?

Suppose a simple bit of C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentException("Text cannot be empty");

        // continue with normal construction
    }
}
```

Would it be acceptable to throw an exception?

The alternative I encountered was pre-validation, before instantiating:

```
public class CallingClass
{
    public MyClass MakeMyClass(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text cannot be empty");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new MyClass(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "acceptable to throw an exception?"  What's the alternative?

Comment: @S.Lott I'm a humble programmer, I know there's always something else to learn, so that I'm open to the idea of some other doodad for this sort of thing, even if seemingly unlikely. I actually read somewhere that constructors should never fail (which is admittedly bull...)

Comment: @S.Lott: Do nothing. Set a default value. Print a mesasge to the console/logfile. Ring a bell. Blink a light.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: "Do nothing?" How will the "text not empty" constraint be satisfied?  "Set a default value"?  How will the text argument value be used?  The other ideas are fine, but those two would lead to an object in an state that violates the constraints on this class.

Comment: @MPelletier: "open to the idea of some other doodad for this sort of thing, even if seemingly unlikely"  What else could there possibly be?  I'm serious.  I cannot understand any other possible course of action other than an exception.  Can you state the possibility which actually occurred to you and which then  lead you to ask this question.

Comment: @MPelletier Add Code Contract (C# 4.0).

Comment: @S.Lott For fear of repeating myself, I was open to the possibility of there being some other approach, which I did not know. I believe I'm not all knowing, that much I know for sure.

Comment: @MPelletier: I will repeat myself.  "open" is not the issue.  You've said it twice. I'm sure you're open.  What alternative forced you to ask this question?  Clearly, someone suggested something to you.  What specific suggestion caused you to ask this question?  Please explain what code you saw or what conversation you had that lead you to see an alternative to an exception.

Comment: @S.Lott I see. Forgive me for not understanding what you meant. The alternative which incited me (I wouldn't say forced) to ask the question is that the parameters were pre-validated, before instanciation. On failure, a message would be shown, and the constructor was never called.

Comment: "pre-validated, before instantiation"?  What class shows the message?  If the instructor  is never called, then the responsibility is totally outside the class and your example code would be irrelevant to how this other class works, correct?

Comment: @MPelletier, validating the parameters ahead of time will end up violating DRY.  (Don't Repeat Yourself) As you'll need to copy that pre-validation to any code that tries to instantiate this class.

Comment: @S.Lott For my defense, the pre-validation bit wasn't my creation :) I just raised an alarm because it was duplicated.

Comment: @S.Lott What @Chad said. There were two cases of the validation in the calling class, which were identical. Even if they were combined, the rule for the class is that the argument cannot be null. It made sense to suppose that the class itself should manage this. Now it's encapsulated, nearly forgotten.

Comment: @MPelletier - Is this specific to C#? The reason I'm asking is that a language tag may be appropriate.

Comment: @MPelletier: Could you please **update** your question to clarify this.

Comment: @S.Lott Updated. I think you've hit something on the head there. The more I think about it, the more that specific context was necessary. Thanks again for clearing things up!

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Maybe not specific, but definitely strongly biased. Tagged nonetheless as suggested.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/159193/1996

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: In all of the cases you mention, it ceases to be an exception (conceptually speaking) and is more of a side effect. Both are valid things to do, but are done for very different conceptual reasons. Don't use exceptions for side effects (i.e. flow by exception), don't use side effects for exceptions (i.e. exception swallowing).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I tend to perform all of my validation in the constructor. This is a must because I almost always create immutable objects. For your specific case I think this is acceptable.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(text));
```

If you are using .NET 4 you can do this. Of course this depends on whether you consider a string that contains only white space to be invalid.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(text));
```

Comment: I'm not sure his "specific case" is specific enough to give such specific advice. We have no idea if it *makes sense* in this context to throw an exception or simply allow the object to exist anyway.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I assume you down-voted me for this? Of course you are right that I am extrapolating but clearly this theoretical object must be invalid if the input text is empty. Would you really want to have to call `Init` to receive some sort of error code when an exception will work just as well and force your object to always maintain a valid state?

Comment: I tend to split that first case out into two separate exceptions: one that tests for nullity and throws an `ArgumentNullException` and another which tests for empty and throws an `ArgumentException`.  Allows for the caller to be more picky if they want to in its exception handling.

Comment: @Jesse - I've used that technique but I'm still on the fence about its overall usefulness.

Comment: +1 for immutable objects! I also use them wherever possible (I personally find almost always).

Comment: The funny thing concerning `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` - just discovered it a few days ago. Got stunned for a moment because it was recognized without me adding a using statement to my own little library. Then smiled - Microsoft implemented almost the same thing I did over a year ago. Nice to see they're improving. :)

Comment: @Developer Art - You may be presently surprised to see 2 other annoyances they resolved: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart.aspx

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097287/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-c - your question made me curious! :D

Answer (score 24):

A lot of people state that constructors shouldn't throw exceptions.  KyleG on [this page](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58922-exception-handling-in-constructors/), for example, does just that.  Honestly, I can't think of a reason why not.

In C++, throwing an exception from a constructor is a bad idea, because it leaves you with allocated memory containing an uninitialised object that you have no reference to (ie. it's a classic memory leak).  That's probably where the stigma comes from - a bunch of old-school C++ developers half-arsed their C# learning and just applied what they knew from C++ to it.  In contrast, in Objective-C Apple separated the allocation step from the initialisation step, so constructors in that language *can* throw exceptions.

C# can't leak memory from an unsuccessful call to a constructor.  Even some classes in the .NET framework will throw exceptions in their constructors.

Comment: You are so gonna ruffle some feathers with you C++ comment. :)

Comment: Ehh, C++ is a great language, but one of my pet peeves is people who learn one language well and then write like that *all the time*.  C# isn't C++.

Comment: It can still be dangerous to throw exceptions from a ctor in C# because the ctor might have allocated *unmanaged* resources that will then never be disposed. And the finalizer needs to be written to be defensive against the scenario where an incompletely-constructed object is finalized. But these scenarios are relatively rare. An upcoming article on the C# Dev Center will be covering these scenarios and how to defensively code around them, so watch that space for details.

Comment: eh? throwing an exception from the ctor is the only thing you can do in c++ if you can't construct the object, and there is no reason this *has* to cause a memory leak (though obviously its up to ).

Comment: @jk: Hmm, you're right!  Though it seems an alternative is to flag bad objects as "zombies", which the STL apparently does in lieu of throwing exceptions: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/exceptions.html#fqa-17.2  Objective-C's solution is much tidier.

Comment: @Ant I wouldn't consider  yosefk.com regarding that particular aspect as "state of the art"

Answer (score 14):

Throw an exception IFF the class cannot be put into a consistent state with regard to its semantic use.  Otherwise do not.  NEVER allow an object to exist in an inconsistent state.  This includes not providing complete constructors (like having an empty constructor + initialize() before your object is actually completely built)...JUST SAY NO!

In a pinch, everyone does it.  I did it the other day for a very narrowly used object within a tight scope.  Some day down the road, I or someone else will probably pay the price for that slip in practice.

I should note that by "constructor" I mean the thing the client calls to build the object.  That could just as easily be something other than an actual construct that goes by the name "Constructor".  For example, something like this in C++ wouldn't violate the principle IMNSHO:

```
struct funky_object
{
  ...
private:
  funky_object();
  bool initialize(std::string);

  friend boost::optional<funky_object> build_funky(std::string);
};
boost::optional<funky_object> build_funky(std::string str)
{
  funky_object fo;
  if (fo.initialize(str)) return fo;
  return boost::optional<funky_object>();
}
```

Since the only way to create a `funky_object` is by calling `build_funky` the principle of never allowing an invalid object to exist remains intact even though the actual "Constructor" doesn't finish the job.

That's a lot of extra work though for questionable gain (maybe even loss).  I'd still prefer the exception route.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, I would use the factory method. Basically, set your class have only private constructors and have a factory method which returns an instance of your object. If the initial parameters are invalid, just return null and have the calling code decide what to do.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass(string text)
    {
        //normal construction
    }

    public static MyClass MakeMyClass(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;
        else
            return new MyClass(text);
    }
}
public class CallingClass
{
    public MyClass MakeMyClass(string text)
    {
        var cls = MyClass.MakeMyClass(text);
        if(cls == null)
             //show messagebox or throw exception
        return cls;
    }
}
```

Never throw exceptions unless the conditions are exceptional. I'm thinking that in this case, an empty value can be passed easily. If that is the case, using this pattern would avoid exceptions and the performance penalties they incur while keeping the MyClass state valid.

Comment: I don't see the advantage.  Why is testing the result of a factory for null preferable to having a try-catch somewhere that can catch the exception from the constructor?  Your approach seems to be "disregard exceptions, go back to explicitly checking the return value from methods for errors".  We long ago accepted that exceptions are generally superior to having to explicitly test every method return-value for errors, so your advice seems suspect.  I'd want to see some justification for why you think the general rule does not apply here.

Comment: we never did accept that exceptions were superior to return codes, they can be a humungous performance hit if thrown too often. However, throwing an exception from a constructor will leak memory, even in .NET, if you've allocated something that's unmanaged. You have to do a lot of work in your finaliser to make up for this case. Anyway, the factory is a good idea here, and TBH it should throw an exception instead of returning a null. Assuming you create only few 'bad' classes, then making  the factory throw is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

- A constructor shouldn't have any side-effects.

  - Anything more than private field initialization should be viewed as a side-effect.
  - A constructor with side-effects breaks the Single-Responsibilty-Principle (SRP) and runs contrary to the spirit of object-oriented-programming (OOP).
- A constructor should be light and should never fail.

  - For instance, I always shudder when I see a try-catch block inside a constructor. A constructor should not throw exceptions or log errors.

One could reasonably question these guidelines and say, "But I don't follow these rules, and my code works fine!" 
To that, I would reply, "Well that may be true, until it isn't."

- Exceptions and errors inside of a constructor are very unexpected. Unless they are told to do so, future programmers will not be inclined to surround these constructor calls with defensive code.
- If anything fails in production, the generated stack trace may be difficult to parse. The top of the stack trace may point to the constructor call, but many things happen in the constructor, and it may not point to the actual LOC that failed.

  - I've parsed many .NET stack traces where this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what MyClass is doing. If MyClass was actually a data repository class, and parameter text was a connection string, then best practice would be to throw an ArgumentException. However, if MyClass is the StringBuilder class (for instance), then you could just leave it blank.

So it depends on how essential parameter text is to the method - does the object make sense with a null or blank value?

Comment: I think the question implies that the class actually requires the string to be not empty. That is not the case in your StringBuilder example.

Comment: Then the answer must be yes - it is acceptable to throw a exception. To avoid having to try/catch this error, then you could use a factory pattern to handle the object creation for you, which would include an empty string case.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to set a default, but I know Java has the "Apache Commons" library that does something like this, and I think that's a fairly good idea as well.  I don't see an issue with throwing an exception if the invalid value would put the object in an unusable state; a string isn't a good example but what if it was for poor man's DI?  You couldn't operate if a value of `null` was passed in in place of, let's say, a `ICustomerRepository` interface.  In a situation like this, throwing an exception is the correct way of handling things, I would say.

Answer (score -1):

When I used to work in c++, I didn't use to throw exception in constructor because of memory leak problem it can lead to, I had learned it the hard way. Anyone working with c++ knows how difficult and problematic memory leak can be.

But if you are in c#/Java, then you don't have this problem, because garbage collector will collect the memory. If you are using C#, I think it is preferable to use property for nice and consistent way to make sure that data constraints are guaranteed.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text 
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("Text cannot be empty");
            _text = value;
        } 
    }

    public MyClass(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
        // continue with normal construction
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Throwing an exception will be a real pain for the users of your class. If validation is an issue then I generally make creating the object a 2 step process.

1 - Create the instance

2 - Call an Initialize method with a return result.

OR

Call a method/function that creates the class for you that can do the validation.

OR

Have an isValid flag, which I don't particularly like but some people do.

Comment: By "Create the instance" do you mean create an instance which is in an invalid state and can't be used?

Comment: Nope, create a default no parameter instance. If it can't be used then so be it, because part of using the class requires you to call initialize.  Sorry, I am not a fan of exceptions except for exceptional conditions. Invalid data is not an exceptional condition in my opinion. Readable and maintainable code is every bit as important as working code and code that uses too many exceptions is anything but readable.

Comment: @Dunk, that's just wrong.

Comment: Java has `IllegalArgumentException` as part of `java.lang` for a reason. The Javadoc states "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument." C# has `ArgumentException` for sub-classing for specific cases. C++ has `throw std::invalid_argument("...");` as part of `#include <stdexcept>` I would say that invalid data is an exception pretty universally.

Comment: @Chad, that is your opinion, but my opinion is not wrong. It is just different from yours. I find try-catch code far more difficult to read and I've seen far more errors created when people use try-catch for trivial error handling than more traditional methods. That has been my experience and it isn't wrong. It is what it is.

Comment: @fuzzy: C++ has goto. So what's your point?

Comment: The POINT is that after I call a constructor, if it doesn't create because an input is invalid, that is an EXCEPTION.  The app's data is now in an inconsistent/invalid state if I simply create the object and set a flag saying `isValid = false`.  Having to test after a class is created if it's valid is horrible, very error prone design.  And, you said, have a constructor, then call initialize... What if I don't call initialize?  What then?  And what if Initialize gets bad data, can I throw an exception now?  Your class shouldn't be difficult to use.

Comment: @Chad, Yes, the class shouldn't be difficult to use. My point exactly. What if I I don't handle your exception. Ooops, very error-prone. Exceptions are not only more difficult to use but harder to read. Either method has its issues but writing code that can be easily read is far easier to do without using exceptions. That alone makes it easier to use. As for bad Initialize data, you simply return an error code.

Comment: @Dunk, if you find exceptions hard to use, you're using them wrong.  Simply put, bad input was provided to a constructor.  That's an exception.  The app should not continue to run unless it's fixed.  Period.  If it does, you end up with a worse problem, bad data.  If you don't know how to handle the exception, you don't, you let it bubble up the call stack until it can be handled, even if that means simply logging, and stopping execution.  Simply put, you don't need to handle exceptions, or test for them.  They simply work.

Comment: Sorry, this is just too much of an anti-pattern to consider.

Comment: Apart from the `IsValid` flag, the other two suggestions are reasonable: The first is common to set up controls that are external to the page itself, and the second is basically the `Factory` pattern.  I disagree on the notion that Exceptions shouldn't be used, but the other advice is sound.

Comment: Agreed, this is a terrible idea. Parameterized c'tors should be giving you fully built and initialized objects. If you're going to do this, you might as well abstract away the validation process and make it a client side operation, which is what you mainly see these days. Calling a constructor and then checking "did it construct?" is absurd.

Comment: What is absurd is having your application crash because some exception occurred that you weren't counting on. I'm sure your customers will appreciate the frequent program crashes that you make your users endure. In fact, I must use some of your programs. If it is important that bad data is caught then the developer can certainly use any of my methods of validation quite successfully. However, the more frequent case is developers not catching exceptions. I'd rather have my application run rather than users having to endure the pain of program crashes that the community seems to be endorsing.

Comment: @Dunk: Even if you don't use exceptions, you should still crash explicitly, as early as possible and leaving behind as much information as possible (logs) so that debugging is as smooth as can be. After all, we're talking unexpected errors here, we can't do anything else. If the error is expected, then you handle it as best as you can, and again you do it the same way regardless of whether you use exceptions or return values. Note that I approve of return values when the error is not "exceptional" (all the `.TryX` methods in the framework are there for a reason) but it's completely unrelated.

Comment: I think the 'IsValid' option has its place and should not be summarily dismissed. For high throughput operations on small POCO's or structs that are internal, for example. Imagine executing a `ParallelFor` on thousands of objects or value types each constructed from a csv line, for example. You wouldn't want to throw an exception just because one out of x million lines was missing a comma. As long as the process knows to check for 'IsValid', it can pass it along to a fallout handler.